# Azure Load Balancer - SSRS Scale Out

Tags: azure, ssrs-2016, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer, azure-vm

I have deployed SSRS-Scale out along with Azure Load balancer. Seems it is working but I see the below error for some executions. Seems Report viewer cache the session along with the user name of local instances in the database and if the successive request goes another instance, it gives an error.

I can avoid this issue by changing the session affinity of azure load balancer (by client IP), but all of my requests will be coming from the same source. How can I solve the issue? Is there a way to remove session caching for the report viewer?

[image]

Comment: I think I was able to resolve the issue. I am going to write about how I have resolved the issue.

Comment: can you please let us know how you resolve the issue